# Choose the right URL to log the scraper

Tags: python, scrapy

[This website](http://www.alloweb.org/annuaire-startups/annuaire-start-ups/) requires login to access the info I want to scrape.
My selectors work as I checked with `scrapy shell`. But I think I miss something for the login part because when I run my script, I don't access to the info.

Here my script:

```
class StartupsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "alloweb"

   login_page = 'http://www.alloweb.org/annuaire-startups/referencer-une-entreprise/'
   start_urls = ['http://www.alloweb.org/annuaire-startups/annuaire-start-ups/']



   def init_request(self):
       yield Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

   def login(self, response):
       return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
                response,
                formxpath=FORM_SELECTOR,
                formdata={'login': 'xxx', 'password': 'xxx'},
                callback=self.parse,
                )


   def parse(self, response):        
       for startups in response.xpath(SET_SELECTOR):


           for company_link in response.xpath(COMPANY_SELECTOR).extract():
               yield scrapy.Request(
                   format(company_link.strip("/")),
                   meta={'cookiejar':company_link},
                   callback=self.parse_company_profile,
               )


        next_page = startups.css(NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                response.urljoin(next_page),
                meta={'cookiejar': response.meta['cookiejar']},
                callback=self.parse,
            )

   def parse_company_profile(self, response):
       for startups in response.xpath(SET_SELECTOR2):

         yield {
            'name': startups.xpath(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'description': startups.xpath(DESCR_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'website':startups.xpath(WEBSITE_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'socialmedia':startups.xpath(SM_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'creator':startups.xpath(CREATOR_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'hub':startups.xpath(HUB_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'phone':startups.xpath(PHONE_SELECTOR).extract(),
            'email':startups.xpath(EMAIL_SELECTOR).extract(),   
        }
```

Comment: Can you first correct the formatting and then post the proper code you used?

Comment: @TarunLalwani should be better like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login code isn't executed at all.
The `init_request()` method is only used by Scrapy's `InitSpider` (which doesn't seem to mentioned in the docs).

The [class itself](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/init.py) is pretty well documented, so you shouldn't have trouble creating a working spider.

Since `InitSpider` doesn't actually do much, another possibility is rewriting your spider with the login url as the start url, and creating the wanted sequence of requests yourself.